# Predicting a single timepoint from longitudinal data

Tags: prediction, panel-data

I'm working on a project and I haven't quite figured out the best way to analyze the data. Any help would be much appreciated.

Design:
Dependent variable: variable A measured at time 1 only.
Independent variables: variable B and variable C measured 14 times longitudinally

Goal: Predict variable A from variables B & C.

I know that if the situation were reversed (e.g., variable B is the DV) then I could use a multilevel model/mixed regression framework (variable A is a between persons effect and variable C is a within persons effect). Any modeling tips would be much appreciated.

Added complexity: I care most about whether the variability in variables B & C are important. That is, do individuals who vary a lot on B & C have different outcomes from individuals who do not vary as much on B & C.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The tags are typically used to refer to the problem at hand. Placing 4 tags for statistical software is strange. I might suggest the [longitudinal](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/longitudinal) or the [prediction](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prediction) tags. Once you figure out exactly what you want to do then you can worry about the software to do it - before that point it is IMO best to keep it language agnostic.